# how to remove duplicate objects with same id's in a set

Tags: java, hashset

HashSet contains objects,I want to remove duplicates whose objects are having same id's

the following is the code..

```
Set<Employee> empSet=new HashSet<Employee>();
empSet.add(new Employee(1,"naresh"));
empSet.add(new Employee(2,"raj"));
empSet.add(new Employee(1,"nesh"));
empSet.add(new Employee(2,"rajes"));
```

//i saw in some blog that we can use hashCode equals method, but i don't how to use that in this context, please help me out

Comment: override your equals method in Employee.java returning true when two object has same id.

Comment: Is that Groovy? Looks like Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode

@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='id')
class Employee {
    int id
    String name
}
```

You can remove constructors as well if [`@Canonical`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/Canonical.html) AST is used. Canonical also provides [`@EqualsAndHashCode`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/EqualsAndHashCode.html), but to add the includes it has to be used separately again.

**UPDATE**

If the class is not modifiable and you have a list/hasSet then you can use `unique` with a closure to perform the uniqueness. Assuming the `SolrDocument` mentioned in comment is referred as `Employee` and you have the above HashSet with duplicate `ids`, then below should work:

```
empSet.unique { it.id } //this mutates the original list

empSet.unique( false ) { it.id } //this does not mutate the original  list
```

Comment: actually if it object is type org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument then what should i do?

Comment: Which object? Why was it not mentioned in the question? Can you elaborate the same in the question, clearly. @naresh

Comment: Before going to anything else, is this a Groovy or a Java class? @naresh

Comment: actually iam using groovy, but we use apache solr,while fetching data from solr it'll give list of org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument

Answer (score 0):

Write equals and hashCode as shown below

```
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Employee employee = (Employee) o;

        if (id != employee.id) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually if it object is type org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument then what should i do?

Comment: SolrDocument is nothing but a Map. Can you give an example of what you are putting in SolrDocument ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override equals() method in your Employee class and it will be taken care of. Set uses the equals method to compare the objects inserted in the Set.

```
public class Employee 
{
    public boolean equals(Employee e)
    {
       /// logic to compare 2 employee objects
    }
}
```